# This Python code for quadratic equation isn't working

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the userinput for a,b,c using a function and it doesn't seems to work

```
import math
def equationroots():  
    try:
         a = int(input("Enter the coefficients of a: "))
         b = int(input("Enter the coefficients of b: "))
         c = int(input("Enter the coefficients of c: "))
    except ValueError:
         print("Not a number!")
    
         my = b * b - 4 * a * c  
         sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(my))
         quadratic = (-b + sqrt_val)/(2 * a) 
    return quadratic
          print("The equation root of the numbers is"    quadratic)
         equationroots()
```

Comment: The indenting of your code is unclear. Why would the result printing appear before the function call?

Comment: it doesn't work because your actual logic happens in the `Except` phase which is supposed to be the fallback/catch-all. there is also indentation issues

Answer (score 3):

You have not used the proper intents, This is what your code supposed to be.

```py
import math
def equationroots():  
    try:
         a = int(input("Enter the coefficients of a: "))
         b = int(input("Enter the coefficients of b: "))
         c = int(input("Enter the coefficients of c: "))
    except ValueError:
         print("Not a number!")
    
    my = b * b - 4 * a * c  
    sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(my))
    quadratic = (-b + sqrt_val)/(2 * a) 
    return quadratic

quadratic = equationroots()
print("The equation root of the numbers is", quadratic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is [very important](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Why-is-indentation-important-in-Python) in Python to separate block statements. It appears your indentation is off, leading to some lines not being executed when you intend.

For example, the variables `my`, `sqrt_val`, and `quadratic` are only calculated if the except label is reached.  This means they are only attempted to be calculated if there is an input error, which wouldn't work anyways.

It's possible you also pasted in your code and the formatting was adjusted, and that isn't the issue. If that is the case, please edit the question to reflect the formatting and indentation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your indentations from the **except** portion. Indentations are very important in python

fix this portion:

```
except ValueError:
         print("Not a number!")
    
    my = (b*b)-(4*a*c)  
    sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(my))
    quadratic = ((-b)+sqrt_val)/(2*a) 
    return quadratic
```

then call your function first then use that to print your statement. Like,

```
quadratic = equationroots()
print(f"The equation root of the numbers is {quadratic}")
```